# あまり meaning "too much"

Tags: grammar, usage, nuances

When using `あまり` in the sense of "too much" (as opposed to "not very"), until recently I had always seen it as `あまりにもA`, with A being the thing that there was too much of.  I never really tried to relate the meaning of individual particles `に` and `も` to the word `あまり` and try to understand how it takes on the meaning of "too much", I just accept it as a set expression.  Here is an example of this usage:

> - あの本はあまりにも面白かったので、読むのに夢中になっていたら、いつの間にか夜が明けていた。

Recently I saw it used as `<N>のあまり` and `<V-dict>あまり` with seemingly identical meaning.  Examples:

> - 母は、私を心配するあまり、体調を崩したようです。
> - その犬が死んだ時、先生は悲しみのあまり、しばらく仕事を休んでいました。

Is this the same usage of あまり?  Could I simply switch to the other pattern in all 3 of the above examples?

> - あの本は面白かったあまり、読むのに夢中になっていたら、いつの間にか夜が明けていた。
> - 母は、私をあまりにも心配して、体調を崩したようです。
> - その犬が死んだ時、先生はあまりにも悲しみ、しばらく仕事を休んでいました。

Is there any difference in nuance here, or perhaps is something flat out wrong?  Also, is there any context in which あまり can be used with に or は such as `あまりに` or `あまりは`?  If so, what is the meaning in this case?  Maybe someone could construct an example sentence with translation using `あまりに` and/or `あまりは`, if it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the meaning is the same, but the usage is not necessarily interchangeable.  According to my book, in the form `～のあまり`, the 「～」 part is supposed to be something that expresses emotion or feeling.  (感情を表す言葉)

> 例：　驚きのあまり、心配のあまり、感激のあまり、懐かしさのあまり、などなど

There is also one form that you didn't mention is `あまりの～に`.  The ～ here is often the さ-noun form of an adjective (形容詞に「さ」がついた名詞が来ることが多い).

> 例：　あまりの暑さに、あまりのやさしさに、など

I'm not quite sure about the formation or usage of `あまりにもA`, as it is one of those patterns that's somehow slipped through the cracks of all my years of studying.  But it seems that they all have the same connotations behind them.