# How to use the word ''Amari'' and "Juushi suru" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, expressions, english-to-japanese, learning, academic-japanese

Was wondering if someone here could help me know how to use the word AMARI in a sentence. And also, the word JUUSHI SURU which means "to emphasize". I couldnt find out when to use the word.

> 仕事で人の間違いを重視するあまり仕事が楽しくなくなった。
>   At work, people focus too much on other's mistakes so work became unenjoyable.

Please let me know if my japanese grammar is correct, if not please correct me

Answer (score 2):

あまり means "so ～ (that ～)", "too much", "overly" etc. You can use あまり in multiple ways.

1. `noun + の + あまり`

   > 驚きのあまり、喋れなくなった。

   This あまり is a noun, but forms an adverbial expression just as "～の場合", "～の時", "～の中" or similar expressions do.
2. `dictionary-form + あまり`, `ta-form + あまり`

   > 驚くあまり、喋れなくなった。
   >   驚いたあまり、喋れなくなった。
3. `あまり + に + verb/adjective + て/ので/ため/etc`

   > あまりに驚いて、喋れなくなった。
   >   あまりに驚いたので、喋れなくなった。

   (Occasionally this に is dropped)

These five Japanese sentences roughly mean the same thing: "I was **so** surprised that I was at a loss for words" or "I was **too** surprised to say something."

あまり in negative sentences is usually translated as "not very ～", "not really ～", etc. See: [What is the meaning of あまり in this dialogue?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39617/5010)

References:

- [あまり meaning "too much"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1866/5010)
- [Learn JLPT N3 Grammar: あまり (amari)](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%82%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8A-amari/)
- [JGram 余り](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=amari) / [JGram の余り](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=noamari) / [JGram 余り～ない](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=amari-2)

---

重視する is a simple suru-verb that just means "to focus on something", "to weigh something heavily". [Tons of examples on ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E9%87%8D%E8%A6%96%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B).

Answer (score 0):

> 仕事で人の間違いを重視するあまり仕事が楽しくなくなった。 (At work, people focus too much on other's mistakes so work became unenjoyable.)

I think your interpretation in English is correct.

As for "**あまり**", I'll show you how it works by using the given phrase.

> 1. 仕事で人の間違いを重視する**ので**仕事が楽しくなくなった。
>      *At work, people attach importance to other's mistakes, **so** work became unenjoyable*.
> 2. 仕事で人の間違いを重視する**あまり**仕事が楽しくなくなった。
>      *At work, people attach **too much** importance to other's mistakes, **so** work became unenjoyable*.

In other words, sentence 2 could be interpreted as:

- 仕事で人の間違いを**あまりにも**重視する**ので**仕事が楽しくなくなった。
- 仕事で人の間違いを**過剰｛かじょう｝に**重視する**ので**仕事が楽しくなくなった。

You can find a lot of examples [here](http://j-nihongo.com/amari/) using あまり in the same meaning as the given phrase.

As for "**重視｛じゅうし｝する**", it is defined like:
*to take something seriously*; *to attach importance*.

There is a maxim in Japanese that is somewhat similar in meaning to the phrase you showed.

> **過｛す｝ぎたるは猶｛なお｝及｛およ｝ばざるが如｛ごと｝し**
>   If I rewrite it in simple Japanese, it will be like:
>   多｛おお｝過｛す｝ぎることは足｛た｝らないことと同｛おな｝じようなものだ。

The maxim is interpreted in English like:

- *less is more*
- *the last drop makes the cup run over*
- *too much of a good thing*